# How does Kubernetes get the name of the current node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

My project needs to deploy a `PV` on the current master node, so this involves a **resource scheduling** problem. I use hostPath, so I must specify the scheduling to the `current node`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-pv-redis-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage-redis
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  local:
    path: /home/lab/redis/0
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node1
```

But I need a `common way` to implement this method for any cluster. What I'm thinking of is getting the nodeName for the current node, which by default is the same as the hostname which can be obtained with the shell's `hostname`.

But I want to do it in a more generic way to prevent it from being overridden by `--hostname-override`.

I would also like to be able to make the **host directory** settings more generic, But kss does not seem to support `relative paths` and the `${PWD}` setting

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve these two problems which include **resource scheduling and mount directory** questions?

Comment: if you just want a local-to-the-Node directory, why use a PV at all, rather just use `volumes: [ { name: redis0, hostPath: { path: /home/lab/redis/0 } } ]` in the PodSpec

Comment: @mdaniel Because we're using `helm Install redis bitnami/redis`, it needs to use storageclass, which in turn is associated with PV

Comment: You might choose one of the other [volume types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#volume-types): anything other than a `hostPath` directory will be managed at the cluster level, and the pod and volume will automatically be on the same node without you doing manual work.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I made pv work by setting pv to the current node using `nodeAffinity`. I don't know if it's an easy way to do it, but it's a practical way to do it

Comment: Cold you describe your actions taken in more detail in a form of an answer?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor My Answer is in the Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

`envsubst < redis.yaml | kubectl apply -f -`

```
# redis.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: List
items:
- kind: StorageClass
  apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: local-storage-redis
    namespace: test-system
  provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
  volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolume
  metadata:
    name: local-pv-redis-0
    namespace: test-system
  spec:
    capacity:
      storage: 8Gi
    volumeMode: Filesystem
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    storageClassName: local-storage-redis
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
    local:
      path: ${PWD}/redis-0
    nodeAffinity:
      required:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - ${HOST_NAME}
```

That's how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already mentioned by moluzhui: the [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity) can be used in order to get it done.

> Node affinity is conceptually similar to `nodeSelector` -- it allows
> you to constrain which nodes your pod is eligible to be scheduled on,
> based on labels on the node.
>
> There are currently two types of node affinity, called
> `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` and
> `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`. You can think of
> them as "hard" and "soft" respectively, in the sense that the former
> specifies rules that must be met for a pod to be scheduled onto a node
> (just like `nodeSelector` but using a more expressive syntax), while
> the latter specifies preferences that the scheduler will try to
> enforce but will not guarantee. The "IgnoredDuringExecution" part of
> the names means that, similar to how `nodeSelector` works, if labels
> on a node change at runtime such that the affinity rules on a pod are
> no longer met, the pod will still continue to run on the node. In the
> future we plan to offer
> `requiredDuringSchedulingRequiredDuringExecution` which will be just
> like `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` except that it
> will evict pods from nodes that cease to satisfy the pods' node
> affinity requirements.

More details with some examples can be found in the linked docs.